# Can you restore log file backups to a mirror database after failure?

Tags: sql-server, restore, mirroring, disaster-recovery

Purely a theoretical question as I've been considering possible DR scenarios...

In this scenario:

- The link between a principle and a mirror server becomes unavailable for a period of time (e.g. network outage)
- Incremental log backups are still being taken during this time
- Then the principle database fails and is unrecoverable

Is it possible to restore the incremental log backups onto the mirror to bring it up to date and back online, or would you need to start from scratch with a restore of a full backup?

Depending on the size of the database the difference could be hours of downtime so it would be nice to know.  I'm predominantly interested in SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012 but other people may be interested in other versions if there's a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

Longer answer, you'd need to remove database mirroring without bringing the database online.  Then it's just a database in NORECOVERY so you can then restore transaction logs to it.  Then bring it online and use it as normal.

Comment: Excellent.  That's how I thought it should be.  Another useful option that I hope I'll never need to know! :-)