# Restore log backups to non-readable async AlwaysOn replica

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

We have 3 SQL 2014 instances in a AlwaysOn Availability Group. Our 2 primary servers are onsite at our primary data center in synchronous replication. A 3rd replica is at our DR site in Async Mode (no automatic failover)

We run transaction log backups every minute on our primary instance (don't offload backups). Our DR site usually runs < 5 seconds behind the primary site, and the business is ok to lose up to 1 minute of data in the event of an unplanned outage at our primary site (planned outages we switch to sync mode and deal with the latency issues).

Sometimes though, our DR site can be out of sync by 20-30 minutes, particularly during index maintenance and end of month operations.

My question is, in the event that both servers in the primary site go offline and our DR site is behind, can we use our log backups to bring the DR server up to date? What are the steps involved?

[Related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59116/can-you-restore-log-file-backups-to-a-mirror-database-after-failure): asks the same question but for SQL Mirroring instead of AAGs.

Due to licensing the DR site is non-readable (I don't think this will make a difference but just in case it does).

Comment: Seems like the linked question answers it since that is the exact scenario you would be in...you would remove the Async DR node from the AG, it would be in Recovering mode, apply all the logs and then done. The only complication would be the connection strings in your apps would have to change to point to the DR node.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't thought that all the way through. Is it possible to do it without breaking the AAG (although that probably isn't a big issue given that we'd be doing it because of a critical failure at our primary site)

Comment: Probably not, especially since your DR node is not readable...and yes, because you are in a true DR situation keeping the AG together should probably be the least of your concern.